# VBA EXCEL Setting print range based on date

Tags: excel, vba, date, printing

Basically i have worksheet that gets updated on daily basis and want to be able to set it up to automatically print each week. Each week lets say Friday it will print the last 7 days worth of data (7 days = 7 last rows).

I have managed with the help of task scheduler that runs a .vbs macro to automatically open the excel worksheet, print and then close.

How do i go about adding the last step to this automation which is to print the current weeks data only and not the whole worksheet.

So i need specifiable column range and for the row range something to be used in conjunction with TODAY function of excel perhaps? if that's even possible.

Comment: Always good to share your code so that you can show us where in the code you are stuck.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Ok good to know but in this particular case i don't have any working code yet apart from the opening worksheet>printing worksheet>closing worksheet which is working. But still here it is:

`Dim XLApp
Dim XLWkb
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.visible = true
xlapp.workbooks.open "C:\Users\User\Desktop\luboil.xlsx"
xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").printout
xlapp.activeworkbook.close
xlapp.quit`

and i run this executable through Task Scheduler. I just need to specify the print range before printing but that im gonna do with a macro within the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the last 7 rows then

```
Dim XLApp
Dim XLWkb
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.visible = true
xlapp.workbooks.open "C:\Users\User\Desktop\luboil.xlsx"
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
        LastRow = xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").Cells(LastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").PageSetup.PrintArea = xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(LastRow - 7, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address
xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").printout
       xlapp.activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet2").PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
xlapp.activeworkbook.close
xlapp.quit
```

Comment: I  placed the code in the "ThisWorkbook" excel object workbook and not general so that the code gets run on start up of the worksheet and i recieve:

Invalid or unqualified reference

Even if i set it as an individual macro and run it manually i still get the same error

Comment: You would need to put my code in your existing code... I will update my code to reflect this.